# sudoers syntax to run shell script as php user?

Tags: php, sudo

I want to run

- a shell script `restore`
- as postgres user
- from php script (the user name is `php`)
- using sudo

the script will have few lines of code, something like

```
dropdb <database name>
psql -c "create database <database name> with encoding 'unicode';" -U edutemplate1
psql -d <database name> -f edu.hourly.sql
```

- what would be the **sudo command syntax** to run the script `restore`
- what would be the **sudoers syntax** to allow php user to run `restore` script as `postgres` user?

Comment: Second part of question will be better asked at serverfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is absolutely the same as you do in console:

```
sudo -u db1inst1 /path/to/script.sh
```

Or even:

```
system('sudo -u db1inst1 /path/to/script.sh');
```

or

```
`sudo -u db1inst1 /path/to/script.sh`
```

Comment: With a default sudoers, that's going to run it as `root`, not as `php`.